# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This class <> does not define an IdClass

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to workaround this issue of a derived identity. In my Spring Boot service when i try to persist LoanInfo() i am getting this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This class [class org.onewallet.entity.Loan] does not define an IdClass
```

The ID generation is handled in AbstractPersistableCustom.java :

```
@MappedSuperclass

public class AbstractPersistableCustom <PK extends Serializable> implements Persistable<Long> {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private Long id;

     @Override
     public Long getId() {
             return id;
     }

     /**
      * Sets the id of the entity.
      * 
      * @param id the id to set
      */
     protected void setId(final Long id) {

             this.id = id;
     }

     /*
      * (non-Javadoc)
      * 
      * @see org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable#isNew()
      */
     @Override
     public boolean isNew() {

             return null == this.id;
     }

     //We have removed toString(), hashCode() and equals() methods. By adding them end up issues with OpenJPA
}
```

In my entity Loan.java i have:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="m_loan")

public class Loan extends AbstractPersistableCustom<Long> {


    /** Disable optimistic locking till batch jobs failures can be fixed **/
        @Version
        int version;
....
....
}
```

After reading some sources i tried annotating entity with @IdClass :

```
@Entity
@IdClass(AbstractPersistableCustom.class)
@Table(name="m_loan")

public class Loan extends AbstractPersistableCustom<Long> {



    /** Disable optimistic locking till batch jobs failures can be fixed **/
        @Version
        int version;
...
...
}
```

After this change when i try to persist the data i get another exception :

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not set field value [POST_INSERT_INDICATOR] value by reflection
```

Any input on how i can solve this?

Comment: Are you using `Loan` anywhere with an `Id` annotation?

Comment: @JensSchauder I dont have Id annotation in Loan entity, or anywhere else in the interface.

Comment: Not sure which interface you mean. What I mean is a different entity which might have a field like `@Id Loan id;` Could easily be a typo from `Long`

Comment: @JensSchauder I meant i do not have any Id annotation (Loan id) anywhere in my web service.